# Error extracting content after a matching pattern using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I want to use `awk` to sort content of an input file into different output files.

#### Simple example

Assuming the following input file:

- `$cat sample.txt`

  ```
  START  
  Unix  
  Linux  
  START  
  Solaris  
  Aix  
  SCO
  ```

The `awk` program

```
awk '/START/{x="F"++i;}{print > x}' sample.txt
```

produces the following output into files:

- `$ cat F1`

  ```
  START  
  Unix  
  Linux
  ```
- `$ cat F2`

  ```
  START  
  Solaris  
  Aix  
  SCO
  ```

#### Actual usage scenario

When I apply this technique to my actual use case,

```
awk '/Certificate Revocation List (CRL):/{x="F"++i;}{print > x}' test_cert.pem
```

does not extract the contents starting from `Certificate Revocation List (CRL):`

Instead it gives following error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=test_cert.pem FNR=1) fatal: expression for `>' redirection has null string value
```

I tried putting the pattern in quotes and all, but it does not work, not sure if the pattern is multiword how we extract the content.

The `test_cert.pem` looks as follows:

```
Certificate Revocation List (CRL):
        Version 2 (0x1)
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = XX, O = XXXXX, OU = 0003 374154744412350, CN = XXX
        Last Update: Aug 15 04:37:16 2021 GMT
        Next Update: Sep 23 03:47:16 2021 GMT
        CRL extensions:
            X509v3 CRL Number:
                209
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:09:DF:3B:15:GE:10:08:D5:86:8F:5B:E7:E6:36:B9:A1:A8:1A:83:18

Revoked Certificates:
    Serial Number: AAS60F19DABCDA8AGHIK3E4A59988AAFDA8E6
        Revocation Date: Jan 29 12:45:09 2021 GMT
    Serial Number: GGF0HHHABCDA8AGHIK3E4A599KKKAFDA8E6
        Revocation Date: Jul 25 4:32:24 2021 GMT
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         1e:cc:8e:9d:gv:ae:eb:0a:67:95:4b:8b:b6:5d:9e:bd:48:42:
         a5:25:e8:eb:b2:22:BV:42
-----BEGIN X509 CRL-----
MIIDLLKKARMCAQEwLLKKAOKONcNAQELBQYYUzvgfzELLLKKA1UEBhMCRlIxDzANBgNV
mZ7YI0YYUzvgrzYYUzvgz9Deb78UGbaedXkYYUzvgr5Hu1Zm16YYUzvgXo67IiNUI=
-----END X509 CRL-----
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem in your case is two-fold.

The first problem is that your matching pattern contains characters that are special to regular expressions, in this case the `( ... )`. You need to escape them in order for your program to actually find the match. Currently, your program doesn't find the match and therefore `x` is never initialized. That is the reason for the "redirection has null string value" error.

In addition, even if the regular expression were formulated correctly, it would fail for anything that comes *before* the first occurence of the `Certificate Revocation List (CRL):` string. So you need to

1. correct your regular expression
2. ensure that nothing is printed unless `x` is initialized.

Your could change your program to

```
awk '/Certificate Revocation List \(CRL\):/{x="F"++i;}{if (x) print > x}' test_cert.pem
```

and it will work again.

**But** this is again an example why *you shouldn't use regular expression matches if you simply look for a fixed string*. To harden your program against this kind of problem, use

```
awk '$0=="Certificate Revocation List (CRL):"{x="F"++i}{if (x) print >x}' test_cert.pem
```

instead.

Answer (score 4):

The input file has an empty line at the top.  When the `awk` code reads this, the `x` variable has no value, so when `print >x` is executed, it triggers the error.

This is due to the `awk` code *expecting* the regular expression to match on the very first line, so that `x` gets set to something.

You could fix this by initiating x to e.g. `F0` in a `BEGIN` block:

```bsh
awk 'BEGIN { x = "F0" } /...your RE.../ { x = "F" ++i }  { print >x }' file
```

This would have the effect of outputting all line before the first match of the regular expression to the file `F0`.

You may also want to discard anything read before `x` is set:

```bsh
awk '/...your RE.../ { x = "F" ++i } x != "" { print >x }' file
```

Additionally, the regular expression needs to have its parentheses escaped, as these are special:

```
awk '/Certificate Revocation List \(CRL\):/ { x = "F" ++i } x != "" { print > x }'
```

Comment: Yes, I understood the space issue afterwards, but still could not solve the problem bcos of parentheses, now its OK. Thanks